# Cómo usar $geoNear con agreggate en PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb

Imaginad que tenéis una colección con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("543f1ec50204444c53ba39a0"), 
    "request_ip": "61.111.36.11", 
    "owner": ObjectId("543f227c0204444c53ba4b28"),
    "loc": [-116.199, 43.6186]
}
```

Donde `loc` contiene la localización de un punto geográfico definido por su latitud y longitud respectivamente.

Y bien, lo que necesitáis es encontrar los documentos de la colección en función de la distancia calculada entre sus localizaciones y otro punto dado.

Para ello, en este caso se va a utilizar la función `aggregate()`:

```
cercanos = collection.aggregate(
[{ 
    "$geoNear": {
        "near": [ 52.15077 , 9.95112 ],
        "distanceField": "dist", 
        "spherical": True,
        "limit":2
    }
}])
```

Al seguir la documentación de MongoDB (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear) todo parece estar en orden, sin embargo al ejecutar aparecen varios errores.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Documents\EclipseProjects\Bonus8\src\pru.py", line 154, in <module>
    "spherical": True,
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1870, in aggregate
    collation=collation)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 232, in _command
    collation=collation)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 419, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no geo indices for geoNear" }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Qué ocurre:**

El problema está en que los ejemplos de uso proporcionados por el manual de referencia de MongoDB es específico para la ejecución exclusiva dentro de su consola (`mongo shell`). Esto provoca que haya que realizar cambios importantes de cara a su utilización en el entorno de **PyMongo**, como por ejemplo entrecomillar las variables.

**Una posible solución:**

Crear un índice Geoespacial:

```
from pymongo import GEO2D
collection.create_index([("loc", GEO2D)])
```

Con esto se especifica un índice geoespacial de 2 dimensiones y se soluciona el error que se producía anteriormente.

**Resultado:**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("543f1ec50204444c53ba39a0"), 
    "request_ip": "61.111.36.11", 
    "owner": ObjectId("543f227c0204444c53ba4b28"),
    "loc": [-116.199, 43.6186]
    "dist": 2.18848713
}
```